# How can I render an html from a json-like string?

Tags: javascript, json

This is part of the response from a server

```
{\"attributes\":{\"size\":\"18px\",\"color\":\"#3ba0dc\"},\"insert\":\"Vocabulary:\"}
```

the page I'm studying renders it like this

[image]

What type of tag/language is that?

How do I parse and render that source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse your data and remove all the unwanted slashes. Your response is in string format at current.

Also you access the object you need to use `.` you get the value of that key. In your case its `Vocabulary`

1. To show the text `Vocabulary` We can use [textContent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
2. To apply font size of your response to the word we can use
   `element.style.fontSize`
3. To apply color of your response to the word we can use `element.style.color`

Run snippet below.

```js
//Your response in string format
let response = '{\"attributes\":{\"size\":\"18px\",\"color\":\"#3ba0dc\"},\"insert\":\"Vocabulary:\"}'

//Parse data
let parsedData = JSON.parse(response)

//Show text on div using querySelector
let element  = document.querySelector('#data')

//Apply response data to your Vocabulary:
element.textContent = parsedData.insert;
element.style.fontSize = parsedData.attributes.size;
element.style.color = parsedData.attributes.color;

//Console log
console.log(parsedData)
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is stringify format of `JSON` data. so you need to parse it.

```js
console.log(
  JSON.parse(
    '{\"attributes\":{\"size\":\"18px\",\"color\":\"#3ba0dc\"},\"insert\":\"Vocabulary:\"}'
  )
);
```